# How to make ASP.NET Core _Layout page header and footer to be fixed on scrolling

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

In my following `_Layout` page on `ASP.NET Core 1.1` app in `VS2015` only the following part stays on top when scrolling:

**Correctly Stays on Top**:

```
<div class="container navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top text-center">
    <img src="~/images/CompLogo.gif">
</div>
```

**But the following part does not stay on top when scrolling**:

```
<div class="container nav nav-pills" >
      @await Component.InvokeAsync("Welcome")
</div>
```

**Question**: How can I make **both** of the above `Divs` from the `_Layout.cshtml` view stay on top when scrolling.

**Note**:

1. I tried placing the above Div's inside `<header>...</header>` but it made no difference.
2. I tried enclosing both Divs with `<div class="navbar-fixed-top">...</Div>` while removing `navbar-fixed-top` class from the first `Div`. But that brought top line of the `<body>` content in between the above two `Div's` (obviously not acceptable).

**_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Company Title</title>

    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    @RenderSection("styles", required:false)
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top text-center">
        <img src="~/images/CompLogo.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="container nav nav-pills">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("Welcome")
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p class="bg-info text-center text-muted">Accessibility Statement</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("css", required:false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What the `.navbar-fixed-top` is doing is setting the position of the navbar to fixed with `top: 0`. To have the pills section be fixed right below it you could create a class as follows: (Assuming the height of the navbar = 50 px)

```
.nav-pills-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px; /* height of the navbar, adjust as needed */
}
```

You will also have to push the body down to accommodate the `nav-pills`. By default, bootstrap will use the height of the navbar as the `padding-top` of the body. In this case you will have to push the body further down to accommodate the `nav-pills`:

```
body {
  padding-top: 150 px; /* 50px navbar height + 100 px pills height. Adjust as required */
}
```